# Magento Database column have value or not

Tags: magento-1.9

I newly created one field in existing table and store that table. It's working fine. But i want to check that field have a value or not.

Field id =`"deliverytime"`

```
<?php if($seller->getdeliverytime() > 1){?>
<p><span> Usually Delivered in </span> <?php echo $seller->getdeliverytime() ?> <span> business days. </span></p>
<?php }
else
echo "No";?>
```

How to i check ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have default value "NULL" you can check it like

```
<?php if(!is_null($seller->getdeliverytime())):?>
    <p><span> Usually Delivered in </span> <?php echo $seller->getdeliverytime() ?> <span> business days. </span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo "No";?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or if you have blank value by default you can check it like

```
<?php if(!empty($seller->getdeliverytime())):?>
    <p><span> Usually Delivered in </span> <?php echo $seller->getdeliverytime() ?> <span> business days. </span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo "No";?>
<?php endif; ?>
```